# How to avoid doing kids CS homework for them?

Tags: discussion

I just went through and answered 3 unanswered questions, and on the 3rd one, I finally realized I was doing some Kid's Computer Science homework for him... grrrrrr.

I've always looked on SO as a site for professionals to help other professionals with problems that are stumping them.  As such, I finally took the time to make a SO account to try and give back a little for all the help I have gotten in the past. But I really don't want to waste my time doing homework for some lazy college student.

If anyone has advice on this, I would appreciate input.

Comment: Don't post if it's obviously homework.

Comment: You'll learn to recognize them with a bit of practice.  One isn't enough.

Comment: When you get enough rep to downvote, do so with extreme prejudice. They are easy to spot when you've been around a while.

Comment: A common sentiment is that the community is willing to assist with an assignment where the OP is stuck, but only with evidence of a very solid effort and an understanding of the problem and solution so far.

Comment: When they post the assignment as worded directly from their homework with no attempted solution, that is worthy of ninety-nine million downvotes.  Doing it multiple times will probably result in an automated question ban for that user.

Comment: My fundamental rules: If I feel like teaching, I teach, if I want to explaining I explain, if I don't feel like answering I don't. There's no point in me having an emotional reaction to someone writing something online; the internet's got enough haters without me needing to get cross too. Early on I jumped on every question I could answer, but after a bit I realised the site coped without me before and will do again in the future, so I don't worry and just write when I feel like it. I think I got more fun from helping than the people I helped got! That's the best way round - no need for duty.

Comment: Michael & Andrew.  Your rules and feedback are well worth reading.  I came away with: 1). help when you can, if you can and 2). Bradley's "we were all learners once"

Comment: A homework question can still be a valid question on SO if it follows all of the guidelines. That doesn't mean you should feel obligated to answer them though.

Comment: I am more disturbed by those who zap out some answer without any effort in leading the OP to the answer at least part of the way.

Comment: Tell me about it ... [I tried to help the OP here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27614388/how-to-remove-a-nested-tag-from-xml-doc-using-qdomdocument) who has not done any work and he even complained in the end incorrectly without knowing anything about the subject. I regret that I spent my time with him, but now I do not want his question to go away because my answer is well-thought and I think useful. It is a bit of shame, really. I was thinking about bringing it up on meta what to do... still uncertain.

Comment: I just add a comment that points them in the right direction, rather than posting an answer for the problem.

Comment: Now you know why I cast so many downvotes :D

Comment: I don't see homework questions as a big issue. A valid question is a valid question. If you don't want to do someone's CS homework then don't bother answering. It's as simple as that.

Comment: Over on Programmers.SE we've got [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6166/40980) which often shows up in comments of poorly written homework questions.

Comment: *"... make a SO account to try and give back a little for all the help I have gotten in the past"* - Kudos.

Comment: "*I've always looked on SO as a site for professionals to help other professionals with problems that are stumping them..."* - No. Stack Overflow welcomes enthusiast programmers too (I think its a good thing, but some others seem to feel enthusiasts questions are beneath them, and it kind of shows in the handling of a user and their question). Also see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10811/173448) (A quick scan did not reveal a citation in the comments, so hopefully it helps you).

Comment: As a related question.  What to do about people who are too cheap to hire a software developer and expect to get their program written one line at a time by using the site?  I for one spent a lot of time and money learning to program over a 35+ year career.  I don't mind mentoring or teaching, but it seems to me we are putting ourselves out of work at times.???

Comment: How many times has someone use SO to help with their work at work? ;)

Comment: Like mukunda, I've added comments that pointed them in the right direction only to have ME downvoted for not giving a specific answer.  So I just ignore questions like that.

Comment: TomBryer - To me, the act of doing homework teaches the student. To do the work is to learn, and having someone else solve homework problems does not help the student grow in the same way as actually doing the work. Conversely, Working is about being productive, my customers want me to spend my day producing useful tools, not taking a deep dive into details.

Comment: I have no argument against a student finding answers on the Internet, but at some point, solving a problem for a student does not help either me or the student. This was the point of my original question.

Answer (score 53):

Homework questions are *usually* pretty easy to spot. They often involve a problem statement (that looks like its out of a textbook) and nothing else.

If you see one of these, downvote, VTC (or flag to close) as "too broad" or "unclear what you are asking" and consider commenting saying that we expect attempts to be shown on homework question.

Finally, if they *did* put forth some effort and are asking a *specific* question (not just "solve this problem!"), consider answering. We were all learners once :).

Comment: re: *easy to spot* they also almost always specify the use of an array when some other collection would be much better

Comment: @Plutonix Yes, obviously bad practices are another good sign of a homework question.

Comment: Definitely, this; I also think of it in a related way: Forget that "homework" exists at all... is it a good question, anyway?

Comment: I think it's safe to assume we're all *still* learners.

Comment: @Jubobs No question about that :)

Comment: @Plutonix Even more than array are the ones looking for an ArrayList.

Answer (score 16):

Pretty fundamentally - if it's a *good* question, according to StackOverflow guidelines, then I don't see the problem. If they've followed https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then they'll have produced a specific question, and an MCVE for the problem they're having.

I don't mind helping someone out if they're prepared to do that, regardless of whether it's homework or not.

I also object to doing someone's work for them - regardless of whether it's home work or not. Vote to close and downvote lazy questions.

Comment: What does MVCE stand for?

Comment: @Doradus http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Spot on.  We should be encouraging good questions, regardless of where someone is in their career.  If I could get more students to ask good questions, that can only be a good thing.  I can't imagine anyone not wanting to help a student who can ask a good question, just because they are a student.  That's counterproductive.

Answer (score 11):

Usually we're sorting out these questions by downvoting/flagging/close voting, or marking them as an obvious duplicate (they might be deleted later on in long term).

There's no close reason like *"This is homework, do it yourself"* actually, that's all handled with the standard close reasons.

My preferred one's for such questions (just dumping a homework task) are

- Too broad
- Unclear what you're asking
- Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

---

Unfortunately new users (who care about our advice to improve their questions regarding the 1st two close reasons mentioned), will often come up with dumping some undebugged code attempts as a reaction on comments or an [on hold] message, which will make the question OT for at least my last close reason mentioned.
That might be a frustrating experience, but I actually don't see a way to handle these kind of questions better.

Comment: Yup; it's sort of the 'downside' of being a well-known site for programming questions. The best thing we can do - for *all* involved - is shut them down quickly (and politely). It may not be often, but I've seen people learn from it.

Comment: Also see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10811/)

Answer (score 1):

If you answer a question and it's someones homework, they are the ones that ultimately lose. Not on that assignment but, on the test, or at their first job. If they use SO instead of building critical thinking skills they possibly ultimately lose at life.

My thoughts on this are.

- Do you not get points for an answer that ends up being someones homework? (yes)
- Is it possible that someone teaching themselves programming reads their question / your answer and is helped by it? (yes)
- Is it the responsibility of the community to protect people from taking the shorter road in life? (no)

Answer the question. Get points, or don't. Separation of concerns says that the moral dilemma is not the problem of SO.

Comment: Well said! But I don't understand why you were down voted.